# Can not start new activity

Tags: android

I have two classes. The main class is BundleActivity, and another sub class.
I'm trying to start sub activity from BundleActivity but It's not working and app is force closing.

Here is my onClick method in BundleAcitvity class:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent i=new Intent(this,sub.class);
            this.startActivity(i);
                            }
```

My manifest file :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.bundle"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
          <activity
            android:name=".BundleActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".sub"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.bundle.sub" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Any one help me to fix it?

Comment: What is the exception? Can you show us the exception and stacktrace from LogCat?

Answer (score 0):

Did you create a class for your sub activity?
As far as I know, all your classes must begin with a capital letter "Sub".
It feels to me as well as if you didn't need the intent-filters you put in your sub activity.

Aren't you receiving any pre-compiling errors?
What's the error trace in runtime?

Comment: Yes, I was about to tell you to check the trace below. There you'd be able to see where the nullPointerException was happening in your sub class